# C # how to add an overload method to the class

Tags: c#, oop, overriding

I need to implement an overload for DisableDigitalOut, just add a "Time" attribute of type int. How could I do that?
    I know this is a basic question, but I really need some guidance. I appreciate the attention shown.

```
        [Serializable]
        public class DisableDigitalOut : Command
        {
            public DisableDigitalOut() : base(20) {} 

            internal byte code;
            public byte Code
            {
                get { return code; }
                set { code = value; }
            }
            internal void setBytes(byte[] bytes)
            {
                this.bytes = bytes;
            }

            public override byte[] Bytes
            {
                get
                {
                    Reset();
                    AddHead();
                    Add(Code);
                    ResizeAndSetDataLength();
                    return bytes;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you want a second constructor with that parameter, did you try to simply write `public DisableDigitalOut(int time) : base(time) {}`?

Answer (score 1):

You just add the same constructor but with a parameter. Regarding the base implementation depends on what is asking

```
public DisableDigitalOut(int time) : base(time)  {} 
public DisableDigitalOut() : base(20)  {} 
public DisableDigitalOut() : base()  {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write:

```
public DisableDigitalOut(int time) : base(time) {}
```

because C# accepts as much overloads as you need, they just need different parameters.